# What is the proper designation for someone who has not finished their master's degree?

Tags: graduate-school, masters, university, titles

If a person has completed their course work but has not submitted their dissertation or capstone project. what can you call them if they are teaching a class or course at an academic institution?

Comment: Depends on the institution.

Comment: Depends on the country too.

Answer (score 4):

In the US, a Master's Degree does not grant a title. So, their title would be the same as if they had completed their degree. This would probably be *Ms.* Smith or *Mr.* Smith. Some institutions might have other titles. For example, a military academy would use ranks (e.g., *Captain* or *Major* Smith).

Also, the title of the person would vary by institution. My guess is the most common title would be *Instructor*.

Based upon a comment by [cag51](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/79875/cag51), the title of *Professor* would also not be appropriate unless the instructor held a position with that title, which is unlikely.

Comment: +1. I would add that undergraduates in the US typically refer to their instructors as "professor." This is not technically correct unless the instructor holds an appointment as a professor (which is unlikely if they are still working on a master's), but it's a benign mistake this is unlikely to offend anyone.

Comment: @cag51 Thanks for the comment. I've included it in my answer.

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted cag51's comment.  "Professor" is an entirely appropriate greeting (for example, "Hi Professor Jones!" in the hallway, or "Dear Prof. Jones" to start an email) for _anyone_ teaching a college-level class in the US, regardless of whether that's (part of) their official job title, or what degrees (if any) they've earned.

Comment: @JeffE I would not address a graduate teaching assistant as a _Professor_ even if they were the official (and solo) instructor of record for a course. However, as a default title in US academic situations, one cannot go wrong with _Professor_ Smith.

Comment: "tile" in the last paragraph should be "title".

Comment: @sgf Thanks for catching that.